# Is it possible to spin another process from within an iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In others words reaching out to the command line and running another command while capturing the standard output.

The reading that've been doing so far seems to indicate that this is a clear violation of the sandbox model and therefore not possible.

You can easily do this is in Android:

```
//This is just an example don't get hanged up on the actual command.
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat somefile.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    logCatTraces.append(line);
    logCatTraces.append("\r\n");
}
```

Comment: iOS doesn't allow a 3rd party app to launch another process.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @rmaddy.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve,  you can launch other applications without capturing their output with URL schemes. The second application could even call back your application if it is under your control.